# placeholders in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template that uses placeholders, where the placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value or format of an input field.

The placeholders work when the input text is empty. But if a field containing previously entered data needs to be edited, the previously entered text disappears  and is replaced with placeholder text when the input receives focus.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

the  Thymeleaf template

```
<form class="form-style-9" action="#" th:action="@{/guardian/save}" th:object="${guardian}" method="post">
    <ul>
    <li>

        <input type="text"  th:field="*{name}"      id="nameInputTextId"    name="field1" class="field-style field-split align-left"    placeholder="NOMBRE" />
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{surName}"   name="field2" class="field-style field-split align-right"   placeholder="APELLIDOS" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{description}"   name="field1" class="field-style field-split align-left"    placeholder="DESCRIPTION" />
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{mobile}"        name="field2" class="field-style field-split align-right"   placeholder="TELEFONO" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{email}"     name="field1" class="field-style field-split align-left"    placeholder="EMAIL" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/guardian/list">
            <input type="button" value="CANCELAR" />
        </a>
        <input type="submit" value="GRABAR" />
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the HTML generated

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="tdk" />

<!-- FAVICON -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/favicon-96x96.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../../images_sebloc/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" />


<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="_sebloc/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />

<title>tdk</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css_sebloc/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />


<link type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!---->

    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-color: #fefefe; padding-left: 2%; padding-bottom: 100px; color: #101010; }
        footer{ font-size:small;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px; }
        a:link, a:visited  { color: #0000ee; }
        pre{ background-color: #eeeeee; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 2%; padding: 2% 2% 2% 5%; }
        p { font-size: 0.9rem; }
        ul { font-size: 0.9rem; }
        hr { border: 2px solid #eeeeee; margin: 2% 0% 2% -3%; }
        h3 { border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee; margin: 2rem 0 2rem -1%; padding-left: 1%; padding-bottom: 0.1em; }
        h4 { border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; margin-top: 2rem; margin-left: -1%; padding-left: 1%; padding-bottom: 0.1em; }
    </style>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_sebloc/side-menu-old-ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css_sebloc/side-menu.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

<!-- Responsive -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../js/jquery.floatThead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>

</head>
<body>




<div id="layout">
    <!-- Menu toggle -->
    <a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link">
        <!-- Hamburger icon -->
        <span></span>
    </a>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu" oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false" onmousedown="return false">
        <div class="pure-menu">
            <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">
                <img src="../../../images_sebloc/home.png" width="136" height="43" alt="POWEREDCUB SL" />
            </a>

            <!-- Notifications Menu -->
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                <li class="pure-menu-title">Notifications</li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item">
                    <ul class="menu_notifications">
                        <!-- General Notification -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon_notification"><span><i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-fw"></i></span></a>
                            <!--
                                Alert counter of General notification
                                1. Add to the div the class show_info
                                2. Modify the number
                            -->
                            <div class="alert_counter"><span>0</span></div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- No Connection Notification -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon_notification"><span><i class="fa fa-wifi fa-fw"></i></span></a>
                            <!--
                                Alert counter of No Connection notification
                                1. Add to the div the class show_info
                                2. Modify the number
                            -->
                            <div class="alert_counter"><span>0</span></div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- No Power Notification -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon_notification"><span><i class="fa fa-battery-quarter fa-fw"></i></span></a>
                            <!--
                                Alert counter of No Power notification
                                1. Add to the div the class show_info
                                2. Modify the number
                            -->
                            <div class="alert_counter show_info"><span>1</span></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- Start Menu -->
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                <li class="pure-menu-title">Start</li>

                 <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item ">
                    <a href="/deviceevent/list" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-mixcloud fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
                 </li>

                 <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                     <a href="/timeLapse/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Horarios Alarma
                    </a>
                 </li>

                  <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected">
                     <a href="/guardian/list" class="pure-menu-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Guardianes
                    </a>
                 </li>

                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Account</a></li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; SetUp</a></li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-tv fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Ideefe Web</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-principal pure-menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Help</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="dm_version" class="version"><b>Device manager </b><span class="orange">V 0.1.2</span><br />© Ideefe and Wits 2016
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <!-- Header Menu -->
        <div id="menu_header" class="header">
            <ul class="menu_icon">
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="icon"><span><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></span></a>
                    <!-- User -->
                    <a href="" class="user_name">Sebloc demo<i class="fa fa-angle-down user_name_down"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-xl-14-24 pure-u-med-1">

                    <!-- Content Left Wrap -->
                    <div id="devices" class="content_l_wrap">
                        <div class="windowHead">

                            <h2>NUEVO GUARDIAN</h2>
                            <!-- Pagination & Search Module -->
                            <div class="search_module">

                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="ico_arrow show_hide"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="windowContent">






                            <div class="store_content" data-mcs-theme="dark-3">

                            <style type="text/css">
.form-style-9{
    max-width: 750px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 6px solid #901E3C;
}
.form-style-9 ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.form-style-9 ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 35px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;

}.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #B0CFE0;
    border:1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split{
    width: 49%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-full{
    width: 100%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-left{
    float:left;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-right{
    float:right;
}
.form-style-9 ul li textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"],
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3985B1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3985B1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3985B1;
    background-color: #216288;
    border: 1px solid #17445E;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2D77A2 5%, #337DA8 100%);
    background-color: #28739E;
}
</style>



<form class="form-style-9" action="/guardian/save" method="post">
  <ul>
  <li>

      <input type="text" id="nameInputTextId" name="name" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="NOMBRE" value="" />
      <input type="text" name="surName" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="APELLIDOS" id="surName" value="" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <input type="text" name="description" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="DESCRIPTION" id="description" value="" />
      <input type="text" name="mobile" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="TELEFONO" id="mobile" value="" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="EMAIL" id="email" value="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/guardian/list">
            <input type="button" value="CANCELAR" />
        </a>
    <input type="submit" value="GRABAR" />
  </li>
  </ul>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="a5ecc9df-964e-4824-8402-926db7f377f6" /></form>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="windowFoot">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-xl-10-24 pure-u-med-1">

                    <!-- Content right Wrap -->
                    <div class="content_r_wrap">
                        <!-- Devices Map Module -->
                        <div class="windowHead">
                            <h2>LOCATION INFO</h2>
                            <a href="#" class="ico_arrow show_hide3"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="windowContentMap">
                            <div>
                                API GOOGLE MAPS (iframe configuration must be width 100% height 100%)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="windowFoot">
                            <div class="windowFootL"><span>ADDRESS:</span> Rue du Marteau Nº25 BTE65</div>
                            <div class="windowFootR"><span>WORKER:</span> Name Surname</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("nameInputTextId").focus();
</script>
<!-- Js zone -->
<script src="../../../js/ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help to see the HTML sent to the browser. Placeholder attributes are part of HTML and don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem. Removing this file it solved the problem

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has nothing to do with the placeholder being set. It may be due to the reason that you specified the value attribute to be "" ie
in the textfields you specified value = "" .this makes the value of the text field empty and when the text field is empty the placeholder is shown.
try removing value = "".